# Github Pages 404 for everything but index.html

Tags: github-pages

I have a Github pages website for our team at http://olinaeromarketing.github.io/. I've tried opening index.html locally and it works perfectly in chrome on my pc. Everything loads perfect. However, when I push everything to Github and try to open it with http://olinaeromarketing.github.io/, everything except index.html gives a 404 error and can't load. I'm pretty stumped as to why this is happening. I also haven't been able to find anything on the web regarding this issue.

The repository is located at https://github.com/OlinAeroMarketing/OlinAeroMarketing.github.io. BTW, the website is currently a WIP and not yet finished.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, Jekyll is used to process GitHub Pages. Files/directories that begin with an underscore have special meaning for Jekyll and are, therefore, treated differently.

Since you don't seem to be using Jekyll, your simplest solution is to add a file named '.nojekyll' to the root path to disable Jekyll functionality.

Check out https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/ for more info.

Edit: Just to be clear, the offending directory is '_include'.

Comment: Wow, I wish I can upvote this many times! I was banging my head on the wall as GH Pages was not finding files that were obviously in the repository. But I named two library directories with a leading underscore to distinguish them from my own files!

Comment: Same to me, you are my hero!

Comment: still saving people nearly four years later.  thank you!

Comment: you saved me today