# Github pages throws 404 in non-index pages

Tags: github-pages

I set up a blog on github.

I can visit the index page but not other pages like "article", because it returns error 404. I have added the repository name in the url but it still doesn't work:

http://marshallma.github.io/marshall/

The above url is working but when I try to click the article link, there's a 404.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you, you should provide more detail, such as relevant parts of your html file, how you constructed your blog, what you have tried to resolve the issue, etc.

Comment: All links seems to be working. Any problem left ?

Comment: Hello! I edited your question to make it more readable and edited the title to better reflect your problem. If you have more specific details about your problem, please edit your question. Good luck! Also take a look at this possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620430/github-pages-404-for-everything-but-index-html?rq=1

Comment: thank u for your attention.I have solve the problem.The main issue is webcontent is different from my local environment.so my url have to add /[myresportioryname].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My probs is about different resporityname for local and remote.main issue is about it has different webroot on the github,Actually I fix it by add [resporityname] for url path.

Comment: What you mean is something like http://<name>.github.io/<name>.github.io/, but that is not really a fix having the repo attached.