# 404 Error on all github pages except for index.html (no underscores)

Tags: github, http-status-code-404

I am experiencing a 404 error on every page other than the home index.html page. Any ideas?

Here is my GitHub repo: "https://github.com/lfalisse/Home"

I've been looking for a solution through other posters but unlike ([Github Pages 404 for everything but index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620430/github-pages-404-for-everything-but-index-html)) I don't have any underscores in my file names.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what URL you are actually using for testing those pages.

For a normal GitHub repo, you can publish it as a [project page site](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages-sites): `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`.

In your case:

https://lfalisse.github.io/Home/

And you can see that https://lfalisse.github.io/Home/Poster/Poster.html does not return 404: it is actually accessible.